# Why this equality?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I'm trying to understand this proof in Fulton's algebraic book:

[image]

I understood why we can assume $C$ a closed subvariety of $\mathbb P^n$ such that $C\cap U_i\neq \emptyset$, $i=1,\ldots,n+1$ .

My problem is why this fact implies in the equality highlighted and why the author changes $X_i$ to $x_i$ (uppercase to lowercase).

I need help

Thanks in advance

Comment: It seems to me that $x_i$ is Fulton's notation for the image of $X_i$ under the quotient projection from the polynomial ring to the coordinate ring of $C$.  In other words, $x_i$ is the coset $X_+I(C)$.